# ActiveScaffold on Heroku's read-only file system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, readonly, activescaffold

ActiveScaffold apparently creates public/blank.html every time the server starts, even if that file already exists (so adding it to version control doesn't help).  This is causing my application to fail to boot on Heroku, since they have a read-only file system.

Can someone please tell me how to prevent this behavior or work around it so I can deploy my app with ActiveScaffold on Heroku?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my rush to get this working I didn't even think to analyze the init.rb file within the ActiveScaffold plugin directory. Therein contains the require statement to a file containing the logic to copy files from the plugin's "public" directory on-server-load.  Commenting out that functionality fixed my problem (after ensuring that I already had those files in their intended destinations).

Comment: can you post an example of what you changed?